# php curl grabbing full page (html and images)

Tags: php, curl

How can I save a remote webpage on my server including all respective images?

I know how to use curl but I want to scan the html code to also store remote images on my server.

Thank you!

Comment: you know you can use curl, so um use curl

Comment: Thank you for nothing @Dagon

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty ways to do so. The easiest might be just use regex and extract all img tab, then download the remote page.

See more here: [Extract IMAGE from HTML using REGEX](http://zytzagoo.net/blog/2008/01/23/extracting-images-from-html-using-regular-expressions/)